# Report is not working on server

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, tomcat6, birt

I created BIRt report and it is working on my localhost tomcat6 and if i am deploying the war on the linux server it is showing me these exception.

**mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar** is my mysql connector placed in lib folder, if i change the password it throws password exception, means jar is correctly placed in the project, but when all credentials of mysql is correct i'm getting this exception trace.

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.service.api.ReportServiceException: Error happened while running the report
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.throwDummyException(ReportEngineService.java:1096)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.runReport(ReportEngineService.java:1316)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.runReport(BirtViewerReportService.java:158)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtRunReportActionHandler.__execute(BirtRunReportActionHandler.java:81)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtGetPageActionHandler.__checkDocumentExists(BirtGetPageActionHandler.java:58)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractGetPageActionHandler.prepareParameters(AbstractGetPageActionHandler.java:119)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractGetPageActionHandler.__execute(AbstractGetPageActionHandler.java:104)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractBaseActionHandler.execute(AbstractBaseActionHandler.java:90)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.__executeAction(AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.java:47)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.executeAction(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:143)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.BirtDocumentProcessor.handleGetPage(BirtDocumentProcessor.java:87)
   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor86.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.process(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:112)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.endpoint.BirtSoapBindingImpl.getUpdatedObjects(BirtSoapBindingImpl.java:66)
   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor85.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
   at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
   at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
   at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
   at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
   at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
   at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doPost(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:265)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
   at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:122)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Error happened while running the report
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.doRun(RunTask.java:274)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.run(RunTask.java:85)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.runReport(ReportEngineService.java:1307)
... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/Statement$CancelTask
   at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createStatement(Connection.java:3089)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createStatement(Connection.java:3069)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.loadServerVariables(Connection.java:4412)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.initializePropsFromServer(Connection.java:4015)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2756)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.(Connection.java:1553)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager$WrappedDriver.connect(JDBCDriverManager.java:1162)
   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.doConnect(JDBCDriverManager.java:251)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.getConnection(JDBCDriverManager.java:212)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.Connection.connectByUrl(Connection.java:234)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.Connection.open(Connection.java:160)
   at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaConnection.open(OdaConnection.java:239)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:165)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSource.newConnection(DataSource.java:190)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSource.open(DataSource.java:178)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.DataSourceRuntime.openOdiDataSource(DataSourceRuntime.java:208)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.openDataSource(QueryExecutor.java:405)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.prepareExecution(QueryExecutor.java:315)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedQuery.doPrepare(PreparedQuery.java:448)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.produceQueryResults(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:190)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.execute(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:178)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedOdaDSQuery.execute(PreparedOdaDSQuery.java:145)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.execute(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:560)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DteDataEngine.doExecuteQuery(DteDataEngine.java:152)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DataGenerationEngine.doExecuteQuery(DataGenerationEngine.java:74)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.AbstractDataEngine.execute(AbstractDataEngine.java:265)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExtendedGenerateExecutor.executeQueries(ExtendedGenerateExecutor.java:205)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExtendedGenerateExecutor.execute(ExtendedGenerateExecutor.java:65)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExtendedItemExecutor.execute(ExtendedItemExecutor.java:62)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.execute(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:46)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.emitter.ReportItemEmitterExecutor.execute(ReportItemEmitterExecutor.java:46)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.dup.SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.execute(SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.java:43)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.execute(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:46)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.l18n.LocalizedReportItemExecutor.execute(LocalizedReportItemExecutor.java:34)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:65)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:90)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:99)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.ReportDocumentBuilder.build(ReportDocumentBuilder.java:249)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.doRun(RunTask.java:252)
... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Statement$CancelTask
   at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.URLClassLoader.findClass1(URLClassLoader.java:168)
   at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:154)
   at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:1)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:149)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 87 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed mysql jar from lib folder, and now it is running well...

Comment: Most likely, mysql connector is already provided in a shared folder of your Tomcat libraries

Comment: may be. but idint get it my tomcat path. but still it's working so................. :) mk happy

Answer (score 0):

Your root cause of exception is -

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Statement$CancelTask
```

and

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/Statement$CancelTask
```

Try resolving these errors.

It may be because of incorrect version of Jar.

Comment: i knew but why this exception is occuring ? there is already mysql connector jar exist in classpath

Comment: It seems it is related to connection pooling. Check if all accessible objects are closed.

Comment: Also Try setting the maxAge parameter of the datasource in the tomcat context.xml - some links says that.